# Using a data attribute to pass information to a modal: is there a way to pass more than one piece of information?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I'm using the following code to pass a variable into a modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
                            data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<?php echo urlencode($parkrow['name']) ?>">Open modal for <?php echo
                             $parkrow['name']; ?></button>
```

and the Javascript:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
    var myData = div.textContent;
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-header').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(myData)
```

Is there a way to send MORE THAN ONE piece of information? I've tried doing it through an array and a bunch of other ways, but I can't seem to make anything work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
<div data-foobar='{"foo":"bar"}'></div>
```